# Run multiple python scripts concurrently

Tags: python, linux, shell

How can I run multiple python scripts? At the moment I run one like so `python script1.py`.

I've tried `python script1.py script2.py` and that doesn't work: only the first script is run. Also, I've tried using a single file like this;

```
import script1
import script2

python script1.py
python script2.py
```

However this doesn't work either.

Comment: Do you want to run them at the same time; or du you want to run them one after another?

Comment: Just run 2 instances of Python interpreter. It's OS 'problem', not Python problem.

Comment: Yeah. What platform? This is a very obvious example of something that should be done with a VERY simple bash script.

Comment: what about running each script in their own terminal windows......?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

With Bash:

```
python script1.py &
python script2.py &
```

That's the entire script. It will run the two Python scripts at the same time.

Python could do the same thing itself but it would take a lot more typing and is a bad choice for the problem at hand.

I think it's possible though that you are taking the wrong approach to solving your problem, and I'd like to hear what you're getting at.

Comment: just wanted to say I appreciate the last line of followup, wish we'd learned more

Comment: what does `python script1.py && python script2.py &` do?

Comment: It does what was requested by the OP - runs two python scripts concurrently.

Comment: Is this is the best way to run multiple python scripts ? I mean should i write the python script to run other python script or directly write shell scipts ? Just wanted to know best practice ?

Comment: I think that would depend completely on the particular circumstances of the problem you're solving.

Comment: What if script 1 and script 2 need some user input? How can we modify the Bash?

Comment: Problem with this option is that imports are wrong(e.g. you want to run a python script in a subfolder and have imports in the folder). At least it does not work for me

Comment: @windwalker it sounds like you don't have Python installed or at least not in your PATH

Comment: @Windwalker the one liner version: `python script1.py &; python script2.py &`

Comment: @ChristopherPeterson what is the recommended way to terminate them. I have a programs that run an infinite loop and just need stopping once in a while (once per two days roughly) and I dont have a convienient way to kill 20 scripts.

Comment: What is the difference between using `&` and `&&`? I want to run a cronjob script parrallel with an API script because the cronjob is calling the API.

Answer (score 57):

The simplest solution to run two Python processes concurrently is to run them from a bash file, and tell each process to go into the background with the `&` shell operator.

```
python script1.py &
python script2.py &
```

For a more controlled way to run many processes in parallel, look into the [Supervisor project](http://supervisord.org), or use the [multiprocessing module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) to orchestrate from inside Python.

Comment: Probably I posted this before or right after the accepted answer. I could turn the question around and ask why didn't I get any upvotes.

Comment: Interestingly your answer seems to have been posted before the accepted answer. There's a three minute difference.

Comment: @logc, +1, in this case the two python instances are completely isolated, correct? If one wanted to compare the output from `script1.py` to the output from `script2.py`, do you know the best method?

Answer (score 14):

Adding a `wait` at the end of the bash script would be advisable, as the script exits when one of the process completes. If we need the script to exit only after all the python process are completed, add a `wait` at the end of the bash script.

So the script would be

```
#!/bin/bash
python script1.py ;
python script2.py &
python script3.py &
wait
```

`;` at the end of first script is used to run script1 & once finished then start with script2 & script3 in parallel and **wait** till all of the 3 scripts are completed.

Answer (score 11):

I had to do this and used subprocess.

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run("python3 script1.py & python3 script2.py", shell=True)
```

Comment: Are these two scripts running in parallel?

Comment: @Snedecor, this appears to run in parallel, rather each script is running simultaneously.

Comment: works fine if you are a windows user then just use python instead of using python3

Comment: How can I specify the file locations for the scripts?.

Answer (score 4):

I do this in node.js (on Windows 10) by opening 2 separate cmd instances and running each program in each instance.

This has the advantage that writing to the console is easily visible for each script.

I see that in python can do the same: 2 shells.

> > You can run multiple instances of IDLE/Python shell at the same time. So open IDLE and run the server code and then open up IDLE again, which will start a separate instance and then run your client code.

Answer (score 1):

The most simple way in my opinion would be to use the PyCharm IDE and install the 'multirun' plugin. I tried alot of the solutions here but this one worked for me in the end!

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
import os
os.system("script1.py && script2.py")
```

and so on you can add ou as many scripts as you want: just separate with `&&`

This is for Windows OS

Comment: or you can also use


'import os
os.system("script1.py &")
os.system("script2.py &")'

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Gnu-Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html) to run commands concurrently, works on Windows, Linux/Unix.

`parallel ::: "python script1.py" "python script2.py"`

Comment: Where should I write this?

Answer (score -2):

I am working in Windows 7 with Python IDLE. 
I have two programs,

```
# progA
while True:
    m = input('progA is running ')
    print (m)
```

and

```
# progB
while True:
    m = input('progB is running ')
    print (m)
```

I open up IDLE and then open file progA.py. I run the program, and when prompted for input I enter `"b" + <Enter>` and then `"c" + <Enter>`

I am looking at this window:

```
Python 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 17:26:49) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
= RESTART: C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\progA.py =
progA is running b
b
progA is running c
c
progA is running
```

Next, I go back to Windows Start and open up IDLE again, this time opening file progB.py. I run the program, and when prompted for input I enter `"x" + <Enter>` and then `"y" + <Enter>`

I am looking at this window:

```
Python 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 17:26:49) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
= RESTART: C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\progB.py =
progB is running x
x
progB is running y
y
progB is running
```

Now two IDLE Python 3.6.3 Shell programs are running at the same time, one shell running progA while the other one is running progB.

Answer (score -3):

You try the following ways to run the multiple python scripts:

```
  import os
  print "Starting script1"
  os.system("python script1.py arg1 arg2 arg3")
  print "script1 ended"
  print "Starting script2"
  os.system("python script2.py arg1 arg2 arg3")
  print "script2 ended"
```

Note: The execution of multiple scripts depends purely underlined operating system, and it won't be concurrent, I was new comer in Python when I answered it.

Update: I found a package: https://pypi.org/project/schedule/ 
Above package can be used to run multiple scripts and function, please check this and maybe on weekend will provide some example too.

i.e:

```
 import schedule
 import time
 import script1, script2

 def job():
     print("I'm working...")

 schedule.every(10).minutes.do(job)
 schedule.every().hour.do(job)
 schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(job)
 schedule.every(5).to(10).days.do(job)
 schedule.every().monday.do(job)
 schedule.every().wednesday.at("13:15").do(job)

 while True:
     schedule.run_pending()
     time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: It does not help running them concurrently, how can we run multiple scripts from inside python concurrently?

Comment: In Python concurrent execution is big debate... Please read more GIL global interpreter lock.