# Running python scrips at the same time with bash

Tags: python, bash, shell

I have 2 scripts that I need to run at the same time. One script collects data and the other plots the data live.

On PC, I can simply open 2 IDLE shells and they will run concurrently but on Mac, that isn't possible.

I wrote the following bash file as suggested in this post ([Run multiple python scripts concurrently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28549641/run-multiple-python-scripts-concurrently)):

```
python script1.py &
python script2.py &
```

But this only runs my scripts one at a time. Is there anyway on a mac that I can get both scripts running at the same time?

Comment: As a note, I am working on a PC right now and will switch to my mac as soon as I get back home.

Comment: you can write it in one line (with spaces around &) and you can run like this as many processes as your line can take :)

Comment: I am still seeing the same problem, where it will only run a single script at a time. It will run script1.py and once I kill that script, it will move onto script2.py. I need them running both simultaneously because one relies on the other. Does that make sense?

Comment: you're starting 2 processes in background, so they are actually running at the same time. Convince yourself by adding some prints to your scripts.

Comment: maybe you'd be better off with 1 script and threads.

Comment: Okay, so script1 is collecting data using an API. Script2 then plots the data collected and updates whenever script1 gets new data. As I run it now, I can watch the data collection (as it has print statements) but the chart from script2 will not open until script1 terminates. I am unfamiliar with threads, would that cause a headache to recode?

Comment: @JoeyB, Try to wrap each of the two lines in place of XXXX: `bash -c "XXXXX"`

Comment: Not sure I did it right but doing that makes nothing run --  bash -c "python Charts.py &" \n  bash -c "python API.py &" -- Is that what its supposed to look like?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it all from within python by using [subprocess.Popen()](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)

```
import subprocess
import sys

s1 = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, 'script1.py'])
s2 = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, 'script2.py'])
s1.wait()
s2.wait()
```

Comment: I am on windows 7 and unfortunately, this solution does not work for me. It is still only running one script at a time.

Answer (score 1):

For my purposes, I was able to find a workaround that's slightly more tedious. I have 2 separate bash scripts now, each containing one of the lines from the above script I initially posted. Running both the bash scripts will run both my scripts simultaneously in different shells.

As a side note, does anybody know how I can do a similar thing, where I use a single bash script to call both of the new bash scripts?

Comment: Joey -- take a look at the python solution below. This WILL work on all python platforms, including Windows & OSX.

Answer (score 0):

That's not true, on OS X (Mac) works as expected.

#### script1.py

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import time
time.sleep(1)
print "script1.py"
```

#### script2.py

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
print "script2.py"
```

#### run

set executable permission and run in shell

```
./script1.py &
./script2.py &
```

and the output will be

```
script2.py
script1.py
```

proving that both were run concurrently (as output from second script is displayed first)