# Execute two constantly repeating scripts from one file

Tags: python, python-3.x

At the moment I have 3 scripts:

1. `executecript.py`
2. `script1.py`
3. `script2.py`

`script1` and `script2` both constantly repeat (Sends emails every 60 seconds). There is no way I can combine the scripts (Because the are looping at different times.)

When I try `exec` or `import` it starts one script, then doesn't continue with the rest of the script.

If there is a way to get it to just two scripts that would be fine (e.g. start script1 which starts script2 at the start).

How can I execute both scripts at once (or with a minor delay)?

Comment: Could you provide the code from both scripts? It is hard to determine how the script combination would be composed without seeing the functionality.

Comment: This seems like the kind of thing that should be done *within* those scripts, then kicked off with a cron job.

Comment: Maybe this could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28549773/4655579

Answer (score 0):

To run two Python scripts simultaneously, you can try this in Bash:

```
python script1.py &
python script2.py &
```