# Spyder: Is there a way to automatically open multiple console windows and run different scripts in each console?

Tags: python, spyder

I'm using Spyder and I have 10 python scripts. The scripts must run independently.

Therefore, I have to open a new console and Shift+Enter to run one script, and do the same thing for the other 9 scripts. This is annoying and I'd like to know if it is possible to automatically open 10 console windows and execute one script in each console. I think what I need is something like a parent script or Bash, but I'm a rookie and not quite sure how to do it.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28549641/run-multiple-python-scripts-concurrently) might help.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Do you want to execute these scripts inside Spyder or on their terminal (cmd.exe or xterm) windows?

Comment: Hello Carlos, I'd like to perform all aforementioned steps inside Spyder. Thanks!