# python run sevral codes at same time

Tags: python, synchronization, pi

is there any way I can run python code in this way:

main code will run all the time ,
once every 5 min will run another function while running the main code.

my code is reading gps signal and send it to my server every 5 seconds.

I have to run another code that check the device cpu\file\temp every 5 min (this part take around 30 seconds )
can both of them run at the same time while still getting gps?

I have the GPS code ready and also the Check code ready - how do I combine them (if it's possiable)

Thanks ,

Comment: Yes, they can. Just start two different python processes from different terminals (as the simplest way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might answer your question: [Running Two Script at Once Using Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28549641/run-multiple-python-scripts-concurrently#:~:text=The%20simplest%20solution%20to%20run%20two%20Python%20processes,shell%20operator.%20python%20script1.py%20%26%20python%20script2.py%20%26)

Based on the answer here, all you'd have to run is:

> ```
> python script1.py &
> python script2.py &
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the threading module, to do this task: it allows you to run functions as different processes seperate from the main program. [Threading Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html)

Comment: Threading does not allow you to run separate processes

Answer (score 0):

I think you should get what you want with the following code:

```
import threading


def gpsJob():
    threading.Timer(300.0, gpsJob).start()
    # Here goes your GPS-code


gpsJob()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # main code
```