# Run another python file from a python program?

Tags: python, simultaneous

I want a peice of code which would run another python file. I would like to be able to run the 2 files simultaneously.

```
print('Hello World') 

run ('this file') #obviously not real code

print('Hello World Agian') #continue with program
```

i really need the programs to run simultaneously. I dont mind downloading a library to do it.

Comment: jut run `import this_file`, it will run the file

Comment: `os.system()` or `subprocess.run()`

Comment: Since it's python code, most flexible to `import`

Answer (score 0):

**Update** from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65689559/run-another-python-file-from-a-python-program/65689851?noredirect=1#comment116172696_65689851):

You can try sending a bash command using this code:

```py
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen("python script1.py & python script2.py &".split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, error = process.communicate()
```

Bash command from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28549773), code to run the bash from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4256153).  You need 3 programs: the first to run this code, the second (`script1.py`) and third (`script2.py`) will be run by the program.

---

**Original**:

I made a class for importing files, although it might be overkill for what you want.  You *could* use just a

```
import filename
```

, but if you need to import files with user-inputted names and reimport some of them, you can use this class below:

```py
from importlib import __import__, reload
from sys import modules

class Importer:
    libname = ""
    import_count = 0
    module = None

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.libname = name
        self.import_count = 0

    def importm(self):
        if self.libname not in modules:
            self.module = __import__(self.libname)
        else:
            self.module = reload(self.module)
        self.import_count += 1

# test out Importer

importer = Importer("mymodule")

""" mymodule.py

print("Hello")

"""

importer.importm() # prints Hello
importer.importm() # prints Hello
importer.importm() # prints Hello (again)

print(importer.import_count)
```

I made this class some time ago for a question that was deleted (10k to view [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65268911/14469685)).

Comment: Yes but importing it doesnt make the 2 files work at the same time. They are not simultaneous, one file plays and then the next plays.