# I want to know python build in parallel (Jenkins)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-builder

Now I'm building using execute shell in Jenkins.

(currently) The code below is built in order. I want to implement this in parallel.

[now code status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iu8G.png)

- (I want) build action -> test1.py ~ test4.py executed in parallel
- Is there a way to build in parallel in this way(execute shell) or other strategy?

Comment: Maybe this is a option for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28549773/8997124

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several options to run things in parallel within a Jenkins pipeline.
The first option is to use the static [Parallel Directive Stages](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parallel) which allow you to easily define parallel stages inside your declarative pipeline, something like:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Non-Parallel Stage') {
            steps {
                echo 'This stage will be executed first.'
            }
        }
        stage('Parallel Stages') {
            parallel {
                stage('Test 1') {
                    steps {
                        sh "python3 $WORKSPACE/folder/test1.py"
                    }
                }
                stage('Test 2') {
                    steps {
                        sh "python3 $WORKSPACE/folder/test2.py"
                    }
                }
                .....
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A second and more dynamic option is to use the built in `parallel` [keyword](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-cps/#parallel-execute-in-parallel) which takes a map from branch names to closures:

```
parallel firstBranch: {
    // do something
}, secondBranch: {
    // do something else
},
failFast: true|false
```

and use it to dynamically create your parallel execution steps, something like:

```
tests = ['test1','test2','test3', 'test4']
parallel tests.collectEntries{ test ->
    ["Running test ${test}" : {
        sh "python3 $WORKSPACE/folder/${test}.py"
    }]
}
```

This code can reside anywhere in a scripted pipeline, and in a `script` directive in a declarative pipeline.